# Emacs could not create org-gcal-token file

Tags: emacs, google-calendar-api, org-mode

I use emacs in Windows 10. In org-mode when try to configure org-gcal, after C-c a a code Google page open and I can get success code. When I enter the code I get an error which is below;

> Make c:/Users/dexta/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/org-gcal/.org-gcal-token
>
> Got error: (error . "exited abnormally with code 2")
>
> Got error: (error . "exited abnormally with code 2")
>
> Could not contact remote service. Please check your network connectivity.
>
> Press key for agenda command:

Comment: This is maybe a bug in org-gcal? In which case you may want to open an issue in the org-gcal GitHub repo: https://github.com/kidd/org-gcal.el/issues